# Spring MVC project not able to publish and run... Message: Failed to introspect annotations

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC application(4.1.1-Release version). When I try to publish and Run on Server I am getting the below mentioned error.

Additional Information

- Using Spring Tool Suite 3.6.1
- Spring version 4.1.1-RELEASE
- It is a maven project
- It does not have any compilation error
- when i do mvn clean install , the build is successful

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'homeController' defined in file
>   [/home/abc/Tools/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.0.RELEASE/base-instance/wtpwebapps/project-name/WEB-INF/classes/com/abc/project/HomeController.class]:
>   Post-processing failed of bean type [class
>   com.abc.project.HomeController] failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotations:
>   public java.lang.String com.abc.project.HomeController.hello()    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:929)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4760)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5184)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1686)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotations:
>   public java.lang.String com.abc.project.HomeController.hello()    at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.process(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findAutowiredAnnotation(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:416)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildAutowiringMetadata(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:388)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findAutowiringMetadata(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:358)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:233)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:924)
>     ... 25 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.isInJavaLangAnnotationPackage(Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;)Z
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.doProcess(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:208)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.process(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:162)
>     ... 32 more Oct 29, 2014 5:00:21 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart SEVERE:
>   Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of
>   class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'homeController' defined in file
>   [/home/abc/Tools/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.0.RELEASE/base-instance/wtpwebapps/project-name/WEB-INF/classes/com/abc/project/HomeController.class]:
>   Post-processing failed of bean type [class
>   com.abc.project.HomeController] failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotations:
>   public java.lang.String com.abc.project.HomeController.hello()    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:929)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4760)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5184)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1686)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotations:
>   public java.lang.String com.abc.project.HomeController.hello()    at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.process(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findAutowiredAnnotation(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:416)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildAutowiringMetadata(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:388)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findAutowiringMetadata(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:358)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:233)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:924)
>     ... 25 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.isInJavaLangAnnotationPackage(Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;)Z
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.doProcess(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:208)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.process(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:162)
>     ... 32 more

Comment: We have to see your code please - the stack trace isn't enough

Comment: Judging from the stacktrace you are mixing different versions of Spring. `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.isInJavaLangAnnotationPackage(Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;)` is the indicator for that. Check your dependencies and make sure that you don't pull in conflicting versions.

Comment: @M.Deinum This shouldreally be an answer, sice it was (for my case) the correct answer.

Answer (score 12):

I had this error when I was importing via @import a class that wasn't deployed on the server. Unfortunatly, the stack doesn't tell you what class is missing, but you can figure it out with removing them one by one and restart your app.

Now, why wouldn't the class be deployed on the server if the project actually compiles?

**EDIT** :
I found out I had the problem when the import is using a class that is on the classpath via a Maven dependency. I also had this dependency (the project) checked out in Eclipse. In this case, it seems Eclipse will deploy the project checked out instead of the build from the repository. It won't look at the external dependency of this project.

The solution: Close all external dependency projects in Eclipse to make sure that you actually deploy the version from Maven repository.

Comment: I had this issue and when i closed importing project, it worked.

Answer (score 3):

You might be missing

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example">
```

in your applicationContext.xml file **OR**

```
@ComponentScan("com.example")
```

annotation if you are doing code based configuration.

Comment: You are absolutely right, in my case I tried to use an array on ComponentScan but it seems that the application didn't like it.

Answer (score 2):

I had old versions of spring libraries in my WEB-INF/lib. I deleted everything in lib folder and tried building and publishing. It worked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the stacktrace you are mixing different versions of Spring. `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.isInJavaLangAnnotationPackage(Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;)` is the indicator for that.

Check your dependencies and make sure that you don't pull in conflicting versions.

General rule of thumb, never mix jars of different versions of a framework (in this case Spring but same applies to for instance Hibernate).