# how to registera class in spring container before it loads configuration file

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

So here is my websecurity class in webapp Module

```
    package com.ioyota.shareitnamchi.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

import com.ioyota.core.util.AppConstants;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.ioyota")
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private com.ioyota.user.security.**CustomAuthenticationProvider** CustomAuthenticationProvider;


    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        /*http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/registration","/greeting","/ignore/**","/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**")
                .authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();
        http.csrf().disable();*/

        // Page with login form is served as /login.html and does a POST on /login
          http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll();
          // The UI does a POST on /logout on logout
          http.logout().logoutUrl("/logout");
          // The ui currently doesn't support csrf
          http.csrf().disable();

          http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(AppConstants.NAMCHI_ADMIN_URL+"/**").authenticated();

          // Requests for the login page and the static assets are allowed
          http.authorizeRequests()

              .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/registration","/greeting","/ignore/**","/**")
              .permitAll();


    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(this.CustomAuthenticationProvider);
    }



}
```

Custom authenticator is defined in other module.Now when i run my application using **Run as**--> spring boot app in STS is works fine.But if i run it as spring-boot:run then it gave this error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'repoConf' defined in file
>   [F:\namchi26july\shareitnamchi-system\shareitnamchi\shareitnamchi-webapp\target\classes\com\ioyota\shareitnamchi\security\WebSecurityConfig.class]:
>   Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class
>   [com.ioyota.shareitnamchi.security.WebSecurityConfig] from ClassLoader
>   [java.net.URLClassLoader@25527c7d]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   com.ioyota.App.main(App.java:26) [classes/:na]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_161]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_161]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_161]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_161]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:496)
>   [spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161] Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class
>   [com.ioyota.shareitnamchi.security.WebSecurityConfig] from ClassLoader
>   [java.net.URLClassLoader@25527c7d]    at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionUtils.java:759)
>   ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalFields(ReflectionUtils.java:691)
>   ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:410)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:394)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:332)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1016)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   ... 21 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   Lcom/ioyota/user/security/CustomAuthenticationProvider;   at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]     at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_161]   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_161]   at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionUtils.java:754)
>   ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]    ... 27 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.ioyota.user.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_161]   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_161]   ... 31 common frames omitted
>
> [WARNING]  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:496)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'repoConf' defined in file
>   [F:\namchi26july\shareitnamchi-system\shareitnamchi\shareitnamchi-webapp\target\classes\com\ioyota\shareitnamchi\security\WebSecurityConfig.class]:
>   Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class
>   [com.ioyota.shareitnamchi.security.WebSecurityConfig] from ClassLoader
>   [java.net.URLClassLoader@25527c7d]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234)
>     at com.ioyota.App.main(App.java:26)     ... 6 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class
>   [com.ioyota.shareitnamchi.security.WebSecurityConfig] from ClassLoader
>   [java.net.URLClassLoader@25527c7d]    at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionUtils.java:759)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalFields(ReflectionUtils.java:691)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:410)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:394)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:332)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1016)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
>     ... 21 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   Lcom/ioyota/user/security/CustomAuthenticationProvider;   at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)    at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionUtils.java:754)
>     ... 27 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.ioyota.user.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 31 more
>   [INFO] ------------------
>
> Here is custom authentication file
>
> ```
>  package com.ioyota.user.security;
>
> import java.util.HashSet;
> import java.util.List;
> import java.util.Set;
>
> import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
> import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
> import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
> import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
> import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
> import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
> import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
> import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
> import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
> import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
> import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
> import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
> import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
> import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
>
> import com.ioyota.core.dto.UserDTO;
> import com.ioyota.core.entity.RolePermission;
> import com.ioyota.user.repository.RolePermissionRepository;
> import com.ioyota.user.service.UserService;
> ```

```
@Component
@DependsOn("repoConf")
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private RolePermissionRepository rolePermissionRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String userName = authentication.getName().trim();
        UserDTO user = null;
        try {
            user = userService.findByUsername(userName);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username or password is not correct");
        }
        if (!bCryptPasswordEncoder.matches(authentication.getCredentials().toString().trim(), user.getPassword())) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Username or password is not correct");
        }
        // Authenticate the user based on your custom logic

        List<RolePermission> rolePermissionsList = rolePermissionRepository.findByRoleId(user.getRole().getRoleId());
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authList = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        for (RolePermission rolePermission : rolePermissionsList) {
            SimpleGrantedAuthority simpleGrantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(
                    rolePermission.getPermissionId() + "");
            authList.add(simpleGrantedAuthority);
        }
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, authentication.getCredentials().toString(), authList);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<? extends Object> authentication) {
        return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
    }
}
```

I have tried many solutions but none of them worked.
Please guide

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629489/spring-mvc-project-not-able-to-publish-and-run-message-failed-to-introspect

Comment: already gone through this.its of no help